# Installing networkx 1.9.1 on Jython 2.7.0

Tags: python-2.7, pip, jython, networkx, jython-2.7

From the official networkx [Version 1.9 notes and API changes](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/api_1.9.html):

> Basic support is added for Jython 2.7 [...], although they remain not officially supported.

How can I install networkx on Jython?

**What I have tried:**

- Installed jython2.7.0 on my Ubuntu 14.04 32bit.
- Tried installing networkx via pip:

`sudo /opt/jython2.7.0/bin/pip install networkx`

which downloaded the file `networkx-1.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl`, but then errored at some point:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/jython2.7.0/Lib/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 133, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/opt/jython2.7.0/Lib/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 325, in run
    requirement_set.install(
  File "/opt/jython2.7.0/Lib/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 325, in run
    requirement_set.install(
  File "/opt/jython2.7.0/Lib/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 633, in install
    requirement.install(
  File "/opt/jython2.7.0/Lib/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 719, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root)
  File "/opt/jython2.7.0/Lib/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 990, in move_wheel_files
    move_wheel_files(
  File "/opt/jython2.7.0/Lib/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 154, in move_wheel_files
    compileall.compile_dir(source, force=True, quiet=True)
  File "/opt/jython2.7.0/Lib/compileall.py", line 56, in compile_dir
    if not compile_dir(fullname, maxlevels - 1, dfile, force, rx,
  File "/opt/jython2.7.0/Lib/compileall.py", line 56, in compile_dir
    if not compile_dir(fullname, maxlevels - 1, dfile, force, rx,
  File "/opt/jython2.7.0/Lib/compileall.py", line 50, in compile_dir
    if not compile_file(fullname, ddir, force, rx, quiet):
  File "/opt/jython2.7.0/Lib/compileall.py", line 99, in compile_file
    ok = py_compile.compile(fullname, None, dfile, True)
  File "/opt/jython2.7.0/Lib/compileall.py", line 99, in compile_file
    ok = py_compile.compile(fullname, None, dfile, True)
  File "/opt/jython2.7.0/Lib/py_compile.py", line 99, in compile
    _py_compile.compile(file, cfile, dfile)
  File "/opt/jython2.7.0/Lib/py_compile.py", line 99, in compile
    _py_compile.compile(file, cfile, dfile)
RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Method code too large!
```

I added the following print statements before the `_py_compile.compile(file, cfile, dfile)` functions:

```
print "file: %s" % file
print "cfile: %s" % cfile
print "dfile: %s" % dfile
```

which gave me:

```
file: /tmp/pip_build_vagrant/networkx/networkx/generators/atlas.py
cfile: None
dfile: None
```

Did anybody manage to install networkx 1.9 on Jython2.7.0?

Comment: reported as bug https://github.com/networkx/networkx/issues/1671

Comment: @JanusTroelsen thanks, Maybe someone commits a patch. As mentioned, jython is not officially supported.  Yet, the info from the below answer should help to create a quick fix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how to get networkx installed in Jython:

1. Go to PyPI and download the [networkx source package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/networkx/).
2. extract the networkx source into a folder.
3. in the source folder, delete the file `networkx/generators/atlas.py` (this is the file that's too large for Jython to parse.  It doesn't work in Jython anyways, so just delete it).
4. in the file `networkx/readwrite/gml.py`, remove all mentions of lib2to3 (due to a current bug in Jython, lib2to3 is not available):

   - on lines 44-46, comment out imports from lib2to3
   - on lines around 75, change:

     ```
     rtp_fix_unicode = RefactoringTool(['lib2to3.fixes.fix_unicode'], 
                                       {'print_function': True})
     ```

     to:

     ```
     rtp_fix_unicode = None
     ```
   - around line 145, in the try-except statement, remove ParseError and TokenError.
5. go back to the source folder, and run:

   ```
   jython/pip install .
   ```

   Or alternatively, if you don't have pip for jython:

   ```
   jython setup.py install
   ```

It should install successfully, and you should be able to import networkx in Jython now.

Comment: The import worked. Didn't have time yet to do more than the import. Thanks for your effort.